# How do I delete all except the latest 5 recently updated/new files from AWS s3?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I can fetch the last five updated files from AWS S3 using the below command

```
aws s3 ls s3://somebucket/ --recursive | sort | tail -n 5 | awk '{print $4}'
```

Now I need to delete all the files in AWS S3 except the last 5 files which are fetched from above command in AWS.

Say the command fetches `1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt,5.txt`. I need to delete all from AWS S3 except `1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt,and 5.txt`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [AWS s3 rm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html) command with multiple `--exclude` options (I assume the last 5 files do not fall under a pattern)

```
aws s3 rm s3://somebucket/ --recursive --exclude "somebucket/1.txt" --exclude "somebucket/2.txt" --exclude "somebucket/3.txt" --exclude "somebucket/4.txt" --exclude "somebucket/5.txt"
```

**CAUTION**: Make sure you try it with `--dryrun` option, verify the files to be deleted do not include the 5 files before actually removing the files.

Answer (score 7):

Use a negative number with  `head` to get all but the last `n` lines:

```
aws s3 ls s3://somebucket/ --recursive | sort | head -n -5 | while read -r line ; do
    echo "Removing ${line}"
    aws s3 rm s3://somebucket/${line}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short story :** Based on @bcattle answser, this work for AWS CLI 2:

```
aws s3 ls s3://[BUCKER_NAME] --recursive | awk 'NF>1{print $4}' | grep . | sort | head -n -5 | while read -r line ; do
    echo "Removing ${line}"
    aws s3 rm s3://[BUCKER_NAME]/${line}
done
```

**Long story :** `aws s3 ls` is returning under CLI 2 file path, but also date creation. This behaviour insn't expected in our script, as we want only the file path to be concatenated with bucket uri.